# Android quiz app design. ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the most efficient way to flip through the numerous questions in the multiple-choice quiz? I would have used `ViewFlipper`, but I use the same layout for each new question so I thought that putting numerous same layouts inside of the `ViewFlipper` would be ineficcient.
What are my other options?? Reloading/ refreshing activity? Any suggestions please?

Comment: @shkschneider Though it could have been better written, I don't think this is necessarily just a design question. I think what Dennis is actually asking for is how the objective can be met efficiently without creating many instances of Views at once. One solution to this is to use an appropriate `View` and adapter combination that provides recycling, hence my answer. I think the downvotes are a little harsh here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is *recycling* of `View`s (or `Fragment`s), and various types of `View` along with various adapter classes are provided that provide such recycling. You've most probably already come across this concept when you've used a `ListView` for example, which can very efficiently display very large lists by only holding `View`s for the elements visible on screen; and as the user scrolls, those `View`s are recycled. For your particular needs now (horizontal page switching through many similar pages) you could use a `ViewPager` (which is part of the V4 support library). You would choose an appropriate adapter that provides the recycling mechanism.